# iPhone CLLocationManager updates every 0.5 seconds

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

For an app that does lots of calculation from the GPS, I need to get the latitude/longitude and speed every 0.5 second to be very accurate and avoid delay.

I am using:

- `[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation];`
- `- locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` function to store the value in 3 variables: `newLatitude`, `newLongitude` and `newSpeed`
- An `NSTimer` object that call a function every 0.5 second.

See below a graph generated by Excel representing the latitude values during 18 seconds:

[image: Latitude values during 18 seconds]

We can clearly see that we have location updates every second, and not every 0.5 second as wished. I do samples driving around my office, so my speeds vary between 0 and 65 MPH. So when I am driving 50MPH, I should get different values for lat/lon/speed from the iPhone every 0.5s right?

Please tell me how I can get those location updates every 0.5s if you know anything about the accuracy with the `CLLocationManager` object.

Thanks!

Comment: The CoreLocation Services decides when to send you a location update, you can't just call it and get an immediate value. GPS triangulation is very expensive and slow the device uses lots of tricks to save battery and increase accuracy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't tell the location manager how often you want updates, but only respond when it chooses to give you updates. The timing of getting updates can't be counted on, it depends on the ease of finding WiFi signals and GPS signals.

Comment: Thanks @nevan, that's what I thought. I receive updates usually for every second, at least it works great. I just wanted to try to be even more accurate with 0.5s, but unfortunately I can't decide this and just have to wait from the delegate to receive the updates.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self     selector:@selector(myTimerFunc) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void)myTimerFunc
{
    CLLocation location = self.locationManager.location;
    // do work here //
}

 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    // do nothing here //
}
```