# IOS Core location manager on a short timer

Tags: iphone, ios

In my ios app I am using core location manager on a timer to get current location. The app is configurable so I allow the user to set it as low as 1 minute. So every 1 minute the gps location is reported even if the app is in the background.

Rather than using significant change for the core location manager I want to continue to use the timer as the accuracy will be better.

Are there any foreseeable issue with setting the timer as low as 5 seconds? My reason for doing this is to get the location, save it in a variable, then get it again in 5 seconds and compare it to a distance variable to then decide if the user has moved far enough and report it if so.

Comment: have look at this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104143/iphone-cllocationmanager-updates-every-0-5-seconds)

Comment: excellent thank you. I do wonder though why they say you can't tell it when to get you the location. I set min for a minute and it gets it every time.

Comment: he say it depends on the ease of finding WiFi signals and GPS signals...  you can see comment on that by Dachmt he receives updates every second

Comment: Hope you wanted this answer or anything u r not clear?

Comment: nope. totally clear. As I understand it.. The location is dependant on the signal. So no matter if I try to get location at 5 mins or 5 seconds there is no guarantee. Not really a problem. If the gps errors then I just skip the update to my server.

Comment: accept answer so others can use it.. @seeleyBoothe

Answer (score 0):

Getting location depends on the ease of finding WiFi signals and GPS signals. No matter you set 1min or 1sec if no signals. Look here in comments [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104143/iphone-cllocationmanager-updates-every-0-5-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

You are following a wrong approach to do this. You need use the `Delegates` provided by the [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) to achieve it.
What you are doing, is completely wrong, why do you want to check the location after 5 Sec if it doesn't changed from the last position.

**The solution to the problem:**

You need to set the accuracy depending on your requirements:

```
kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
kCLLocationAccuracyBest
kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
```

You will get the call on the delegate method, whenever there is specific change in the location:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

It will save the battery as well as increases the performance as it will save the unnecessary call to get the location again and again.